# Autohotkey: Commands with Alt Key Working Properly only if not Restricted to a Specific Application

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to add custom keyboard commands to an application using Autohotkey.
In many of these hotkeys I would like to use the <kbd>alt</kbd> key in combination with some other key of my choice (any of the standard letters).

All works fine as long as I don't restrict their usage in such a manner that they work in the target application only (via the #IfWinActive directive ). If I do so, the hotkeys themselves still work, however their behavior is very strange.

I found that they get activated either if

a) I hold down the alt key and then press the second key (in my case the 'b' key) twice
or

b) I use this hotkey two times consecutively with a very short delay between the two triggerings
- The above two cases might actually be 1 case. I'm not sure...

- I have no problems when doing the same with <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.
- The 'b' key is not what's causing the problem - no <kbd>alt</kbd> + 'letter' combination works.
- I have tried all SendModes, but so far with no effect.

Code sample:

```
#IfWinActive, MyAppTitle ahk_class MyAppClass
!b::
click 367, 86
return
```

Comment: Can you also create a sample which windows notepad or any other application included in windows? And which version of windows are you using?

Comment: I'm running Windows 7. The program I'm trying to work with is not included in Windows by default. In fact, it's not even made by Microsoft.

Comment: I understand, but I would like to see this strange behaviour. So when you try this with windows notepad or calculator, is the same happening? I don't want to install any other application, but I can easily try it with applications included with windows.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+letter commands in AutoHotkey such as `!b` work without issue. It's possible the version at the time of this post contained certain bugs or was out of date from the current version.

For your code, it could be done like so:

```
!b::
WinGetTitle, Title, A
if (RegExMatch(Title, "MyAppTitle"))
{
    MouseClick, left, 367, 86
}
return
```